# Open in... for custom file type works in iOS 5, 6 & 7 but not iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios, info.plist, uti

I have an app that declares a custom file type (which is just some XML) and when iOS encounters this file on iOS 5, 6 & 7, it knows what to do with it - my app fires up and the file imports just fine.

However on iOS 4.3.3, the custom file type just seems to be thought of as plain text - the email client displays it as such and doesn't give the option to open the file in my app.

Here are the appropriate parts of my app's Info.plist:

```
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>iBlueSky Format</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>uk.co.tenero.ibluesky</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>

<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>iBlueSky File</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>uk.co.tenero.ibluesky</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>bsky</string>
            </array>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/xml</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Support for manipulating files like this came in iOS 3.2, so it *should* work.

I'm intending to drop support for iOS 4, 5 & 6 in the next major update, but I would like to give users on older devices one more release with this functionality.

Comment: Do you have some analytics on how many users you have on iOS 4 ?

Comment: Not currently - I've evaluated a few analytics solutions, but haven't found one I'm completely happy with (toxic T&Cs, missing functionality etc.)

Comment: Not that it solves the question, but it seems unlikely that you need to support iOS 4 any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I needed to define the app as both the owner *and* the editor of the file type. On later versions of iOS, it seems defining your app as the owner is sufficient to imply the editor role:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
<string>Editor</string>
```